# Flutter: How can I access and print the elevation element alone from this .json response?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using http to send requests to Google's elevation API. I can't figure out how to grab the elevation result alone. i've tried adding ['elevation'][0]) and a bunch of other things. I can't wrap my head around working with .json data.

This is what my response looks like:

[image]

Here's my code:

```
class Album {
  final List<dynamic> results;

  Album({this.results});

  factory Album.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> parsedJson) {
    return Album(results: parsedJson
    ['results'];
  }
}


FutureBuilder<Album>(
              future: futureAlbum,
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  return Text(snapshot.data.results.toString(),
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white));
                } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                  return Text("${snapshot.error}",
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white));
                }
                // By default, show a loading spinner.
                return CircularProgressIndicator();
              },
            ),
```

Does anybody know how to do this? And does anybody know why the elevation seems to be wrong everywhere... Mt Fuji for example showing 1000 meters lower than it actually is.

Answer (score 0):

I gave up and settled for this:

```
text: snapshot.data.results.toString().substring(2, 16),
```

If anyone has a better solution, i'd appreciate it

edit:

solved /w this: https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/